# What is preventing my layout updates from being displayed

Tags: magento

I am trying to display a simple message on my Magento site using a special block that I have created. I have been able to easily unset blocks and insert them in other places on the home page, but I am running into trouble when I try to do the same thing on one of the product pages. I have created a file at app/design/frontend/base/default/layout/packagename/modulename.xml
with the following contents:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout>
    <default>
        <reference name="product.info">
            <block type="core/text" name="free_shipping">
                <action method="setText"><text><![CDATA[<div>Free Shipping!</div>]]>            </text></action>
            </block>
        </reference>

        <reference name="header">
            <action method="unsetChild">
                <name>top.search</name>
            </action>
        </reference>

    </default>
</layout>
```

It seems to me like the code above would remove the search bar from a product page and add a block in the product info section that says "Free shipping!" but when I load the page there are no changes. I have tried using "remove" to alter some of the blocks on the page and it works, so the file is definitely being loaded into the layout.xml. I have also tried making my changes in the local.xml file instead, with the same results. Other than that, I am kind of at a loss for things to try to get this to work correctly.

Edit: To provide some more information on the problem, if I were to replace my changes with something like

```
<reference name="root">
    <action method="unsetChild">
        <name>header</name>
    </action>
</reference>
```

The header is sucessfully removed. So I guess the question now is, why does calling unset child work as expected when used on the "root" block but not on "header"?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to be more specific with your layout handler, you are setting it as  and that means all pages, i recommend you change that handler by

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout>
    <catalog_product_view>
        <reference name="product.info">
            <block type="core/text" name="free_shipping">
                <action method="setText"><text><![CDATA[<div>Free Shipping!</div>]]>                </text></action>
            </block>
        </reference>

        <reference name="product.info">
            <block name="header">
                <action method="unsetChild">
                    <name>top.search</name>
                </action>
            </block>
        </reference>
    </catalog_product_view>
</layout>
```

Greetings.

Comment: Thank you for the idea, but I just tried this and it does not change the output. Additionally, when using the default handle, if I were to remove my two reference tags and replace them with something like '<remove name="top.search"/>' the block is removed successfully, so that makes me think that the handle being used is not the problem.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, never put your stuff in the base/default folder.

On to your question. What if you try it like this:

```
<reference name="header">
    <action method="unsetChild">
        <name>top.search</name>
    </action>
</reference>
```

To answer your other question:

> The header is sucessfully removed. So I guess the question now is, why does calling unset child work as expected when used on the "root" block but not on "header"?

It's not the fact it's on the root block, it's that you should use unsetChild within the `<reference/>` part.

Comment: I was under the impression that there is nothing wrong with creating layout or template files in the base/default folder, you only run into problems if you were to edit existing files, so I'd be interested to hear why you say that. But as far as the question goes, I made a mistake writing the question, the code that I am using is identical to what you suggested. Thanks for pointing that out!

Comment: I've edited the question to reflect the code that I am actually using.

Comment: I would like to point you to this article: http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/magentos-theme-hierarchy

Comment: Thanks for your help and the link Mike. Yeah, I guess it would be better to create a new theme and put the layout file there. But what I'm really concerned with is why 'unsetChild' is behaving differently in the 2 cases that I mentioned.

Comment: Something else that I could think of is maybe your unsetChild being overwritten now by the XML which sets the `top.search`.

Could you try the same, but now using a different package and theme? So instead of base/default, use `<your_package>/default` with local.xml to modify the layout